# Async Error handling Wrapper does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I am trying to write a wrapper for express callback function **displayUsers()** in this case, it would append error handling logic to avoid using try catch everywhere.

The main issue is that fn() actually executes before being invoked by router.get
I am not sure why as I am returning it within a function, not executing it.

```javascript
    ///Userroute.js
    var router = require('express').Router();
    var userModel = require('../models/user');
    var asyncErrorHandler = require('../helpers/asyncErrorHandler');


    var viewsDir = '../views/';
      // get users from model

    var displayUsers = async function(req, res, next) {
        var users = await userModel.getUsers(); 
        console.log(users);
        res.render(`${viewsDir}/users.hbs`, {users:users})
    };
        var safeDisplayUsersfn = asyncErrorHandler(displayUsers);

    router.get('/', safeDisplayUsersfn);
```

```javascript
    //asyncErrorHandler.js
    module.exports = function (fn) {
        return async function(req, res) {
        try{
            await fn();
        }catch(error){
            console.log('Error happened' + error);
            res.status(500).send('Unexpected Error');
        }finally{
        }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

fn() was executing correctly, what needed to be done is to pass parameters to the executing function: fn(req,res,next); Like:

```
module.exports = function (fn) {
    return async function(req, res, next) {
    try{
        await fn(req, res, next);
    }catch(error){
        console.log('Error happened' + error);
        res.status(500).send('Unexpected Error');
    }finally{
    }
 }
}
```